# Как разнести данные в таблице с помощью Pandas

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe

Сейчас у меня выглядит все так

```
labirint_price_series = pd.Series(labirint_price, name='Лабиринт')
labirint_sale_price_series = pd.Series(labirint_sale_price, name='Лабиринт Скидка')
labirint_book_state_series = pd.Series(labirint_book_state, name='Лабиринт Наличие')
labirint_percent_sale_series = pd.Series(labirint_percent_sale, name='Лабиринт процент скидки')
record_term = pd.Series(labirint_term, name='Категория')

df = pd.concat([ean, labirint_price_series, labirint_sale_price_series, 
labirint_percent_sale_series, labirint_book_state_series, record_term], axis=1)
df.to_excel('C:\priceUpdater\Лабиринт.xlsx', index=False)
```

в итоге получаю данные в excel 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне разнести данные в столбце Категория разделенные обратным слешом в отдельные ячейки?

чтобы получилось, что-то вроде этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для возможности воспроизведения примера.

```
import pandas as pd

ean = pd.Series(['9785222239445', '9785222232088'], name='EAN')
labirint_price_series = pd.Series([313, 222], name='Лабиринт')
labirint_sale_price_series = pd.Series(['228', '178'], name='Лабиринт Скидка')
labirint_book_state_series = pd.Series(['На складе', 'На складе'], name='Лабиринт Наличие')
labirint_percent_sale_series = pd.Series([27, 20], name='Лабиринт Скидка')
record_term = pd.Series(['Книги / \nУчебная, методическая литература и словари / \nКниги для школы / \nИностранные языки / \nАнглийский язык в школе / \nСправочники, учебные пособия по английскому языку / \n"Английский язык. Занимательное чтение с упражнениями для младших школьников" Анна Малинина', 'Книги / \nКниги для детей / \nДетский досуг / \nРаскраски для детей / \nРаскраски с играми и заданиями / \n"Машины-Роботы. К цели! Книжка-раскраска с наклейками"'], name='Категория')
df = pd.concat([ean, labirint_price_series, labirint_sale_price_series, 
labirint_percent_sale_series, labirint_book_state_series, record_term], axis=1)
```

Comment: @MaxU Данные я получаю с помощью парсинга страницы.

Comment: @MaxU Все ниже добавил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['tmp'] = df['Категория'].str.partition(r'/')[2].str.lstrip()
df['Категория'] = df['Категория'].str.split('\s*/\s*', expand=False).str[0]
res = df.join(df.pop('tmp').str.split('\s*/\s*', expand=True))
res.to_excel('C:\priceUpdater\Лабиринт.xlsx', index=False)
```

Результат:

```
In [60]: res
Out[60]:
             EAN  Лабиринт  ...                                                  4                                                  5
0  9785222239445       313  ...  Справочники, учебные пособия по английскому языку  "Английский язык. Занимательное чтение с упраж...
1  9785222232088       222  ...  "Машины-Роботы. К цели! Книжка-раскраска с нак...                                               None

[2 rows x 12 columns]

In [61]: res.columns
Out[61]: Index(['EAN', 'Лабиринт', 'Лабиринт Скидка', 'Лабиринт Скидка', 'Лабиринт Наличие', 'Категория', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='object')
```

Comment: не поможете с выводом данных в таблицу excel? как на второй картинке? не совсем понимаю, как мне по вашему примеру соединить все данные и записать их в таблицу.

Comment: @shatoidil, дополнил ответ

Comment: Unable to open 'hashtable_class_helper.pxi': File not found (file:///c:/users/dalcaev/desktop/marketinglabirint/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi). Пишет такую ошибку. Может я что-то не то делаю? https://pastebin.com/bjWCmr3r

Comment: @shatoidil, похоже на баг. Я использую Pandas 0.24.2 , Python 3.6.8 - воспроизвести вашу ошибку не могу...

Comment: Все разобрался. Спасибо огромное!